# create column based on column values - merge integers

Tags: pandas, calculated-columns

I would like to create a new column "Group". The integer values from column "Step_ID" should be converted into 1 and 2. The fist two values should be converted to 1, the second two values to 2, the third two values to 1 etc. See the image below.

[image]

```
import pandas as pd  
data = {'Step_ID': [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 8, 8, 9, 10, 11, 11]}  
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
m = (df.Step_ID % 2) + df.Step_ID
df['new_group'] = (m.ne(m.shift()).cumsum() % 2).replace(0,2)
```

##### OUTPUT:

```
    Step_ID  new_group
0         1          1
1         1          1
2         2          1
3         2          1
4         3          2
5         4          2
6         5          1
7         6          1
8         6          1
9         7          2
10        8          2
11        8          2
12        9          1
13       10          1
14       11          2
15       11          2
```